# jquery add option in drop down

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

I have a request where I need to create a drop down with page numbers in a paginated result set. The results have 200.000 pages, so the dropdown will have 200.000 options. ( Don't ask why... it's the specification :) ).

When I run in my jquery code the for loop to execute the 200.000iterations and add that many options, the page gets very slow ( Internet explorer stops responding ).

Is there any optimised way to add options in dropdown using jQuery?

What I do now is:

```
for (var i=1; i<= pages ;i++) {
    select.options[i] = new Option(i, i);
}
```

Comment: "200.000 options" ? It is just too many!

Comment: Way too many options. I would suggest having links for first, last, and a few in either direction from the current page, and then a text box where you can enter the page you want to jump to.

Comment: The browser is free zed. why don't you try with infinite srolling

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i=1; i<= pages ;i++) {
$('#yourddl').append($('<option>', { 
        value: value,
        text : value 
    }));
}
```

here is a sample

```
$("#btn").click(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < $('#tst').val(); i++) {
        $('#yourddl').append($('<option>', {
            value: i,
            text: i
        }));
    }
});
```

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/8rW8V/1/)

Comment: Did you try it with 200.000 options as in my question? It doesn't seem any faster...